# Remove sharedpreference value automatically?

Tags: android

Is there any way to remove sharedpreference's particular key value pair automatically after a regular time? My requirement is to clear a particular key value pair after one day of its creation to reduce the memory. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried **mEditor.remove("key")**?

Comment: You can schedule an alarm and remove the particular key value pair when the alarm is triggered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule a task using Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889775/how-to-schedule-a-task-using-alarm-manager)

Answer (score 0):

To Particular Field Remove:~

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.remove() followed by a commit()
```

Comment: He's not asking that. He wants to execute this command at a future time, say 24hrs later.

Comment: Want to execute this code after a particular time limit automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AlarmManager and set alarm for 24 hrs. Then in alarm reciever, remove the value by using **mEditor.remove("key")**

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. But I'd better have this closed as a duplicate of some AlarmManager question.